# Calling server function onclick and returning templated html

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to call the `getArtistName()` function from the code.gs file every time i click the '+' button from the `var buttonTemplate` in the `createArtistList()` function.

What it does right now is:

- when the `var buttonTemplate = '<li><a onClick="addArtist(); return false;" href="">buttonCell</a></li>';` gets clicked on the web app, it runs the `addArtist()` function in the js.html file
- which then calls the `writeArtistName()` function in the code.gs file, and writes the value that was inputted into the prompt into the spreadsheet.

I need it to also call the `getArtistName()` function in the code.gs file so i can update the web app with the value that was just inputted into the spreadsheet.

Does google apps script support real time updating like that?

Is there a way to call 2 functions simultaneously from google.script.run?

Example:

```
google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(writeSuccess(artistName))
      .withFailureHandler(writeFailure)
      .writeArtistName(artistName);
```

Add something like this - `.writeArtistName(artistName), .getArtistName();`?

---

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= getContent("js") ?>
    <?!= getContent("css") ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- //nav tabs// -->
    <div id="artistTabs">
      <ul id="artistList">
        <?!= createArtistList(); ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

js.html:

```
<script>
function addArtist()
{
  var artistName = prompt("enter artist whole first name and initial of last name");

  if (artistName === "") //user pressed 'ok' but input field was empty
  {
    return;
  }
  else if (artistName != "" && artistName !== null) //user inputs something and hits 'ok'
  {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(writeSuccess(artistName))
      .withFailureHandler(writeFailure)
      .writeArtistName(artistName);
  }
  else //user hits 'cancel' or 'x'
  {
    return;
  }
}

function writeSuccess(artistName)
{
  console.log("write success: " + artistName);
}

function writeFailure()
{
  console.log("write failure - email myself why it failed and the time it failed");
}

function test()
{
  console.log("test"); //open this artists spreadsheet
}
</script>
```

code.gs:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

function doGet()
{
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function getContent(filename)
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function createArtistList()
{
  //button
  var buttonStartingRow = 2;
  var buttonStartingColumn = 1;

  var buttonCell = sheet.getRange(buttonStartingRow, buttonStartingColumn).getValue();

  var x = '<li><a onClick="addArtist(); return false; return getArtistName();" href="">';
  var y = buttonCell;
  var z = '</a></li>';

  var buttonTemplate = x + y + z;

  //artist names
  var artistsOutput = '';

  var startingRow = 2;
  var startingColumn = 1;
  var howManyRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var howManyColumns = 1;

  var allArtistsArray = sheet.getRange(startingRow, startingColumn, howManyRows, howManyColumns).getValues(); //get every name in 1st column after second row

  for (i = 0; i < allArtistsArray.length; i++)
  {
    allArtistsArray = allArtistsArray.filter(function(n){return n[0] !== '' && n[0] !== buttonCell}); //filter 'buttonCell' value and blank rows
    allArtistsArray = allArtistsArray.toString().split(","); //flatten 2d array to 1d array

    if (allArtistsArray == '')
    {
      Logger.log("array = blank");
      return buttonTemplate;
      break; //leave loop and only return 'buttonTemplate'
    }
    else
    {
      var x1 = '<li><a onClick="test(); return false;" href="">';
      var z1 = '</a></li>';

      var _1 = allArtistsArray[i];
      var _2 = x1 + _1 + z1;

      artistsOutput += _2
    }
  }
  return buttonTemplate + artistsOutput; //return 'buttonTemplate' and every value from spreadsheet that is not blank
}

function writeArtistName(artistName)
{
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; //gets next unused row
  var column = 1; //first column
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, column);

  lastCell.setValue(artistName); //sets next blank row as artistName
}

function getArtistName()
{
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //gets last row with content
  var column = 1;

  var lastArtist = sheet.getRange(lastRow, column).getValue(); //gets last row with artistName

  //Logger.log(lastArtist);

  var x = '<li><a onClick="test(); return false;" href="#">';
  var y = lastArtist;
  var z = '</a></li>';

  var xyz = x + y + z;

  Logger.log(xyz);

  return xyz;
}

//figure out how to call getArtistName() from buttonTemplate onClick
//and have the artist name from last row return and display in the list
```

Comment: You can make multiple subsequent calls to `google.script.run.func()`  The `google.script.run` client side API does not stop to wait for a callback before running the next line of code in the client.  You can't chain a second function call to one `google.script.run` instance, but you can simply put a second complete call right after the first one.  There is no guarantee of the order in which the server functions will complete the callback.  The second `google.script.run` could finish first.  So if the second `withSuccessHandler()` depends on the first one completing, there will be a problem.

Comment: JavaScript functions on the Google server will run concurrently.  It's not the same as JavaScript running in your browser.

Comment: This line: `withSuccessHandler(writeSuccess(artistName))` has an error.  It must be:  `withSuccessHandler(writeSuccess)`  The return from the server automatically gets sent to the argument in the parenthesis of the success handler function.  All you need is a return statement in the server function, which you don't have, and an argument in the parenthesis of the success function, which you have.

Comment: should i return the getArtistName() function contents from the writeArtistName() function? would that display it on the web app onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a good reason you can't have a single server function that does both?

So something like:

```
function writeAndGetArtistName(artistName)
{
  writeArtistName(artistName);
  return getArtistName();
}
```

Then your client code would just call this one function.

Though if I'm understanding what you're trying to do here, and your getArtistName function is just getting the same artistName that writeArtistName just added to the spreadsheet, it might be easier to just pass artistName to getArtistName and then you get to skip these three lines of code:

```
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //gets last row with content
  var column = 1;

  var lastArtist = sheet.getRange(lastRow, column).getValue(); //gets last row with artistName
```

Comment: now that you mention it, i could just have it in one function. but the problem comes from trying to display the value that got input into the spreadsheet to the web app when the button gets clicked. im not really sure how to go about that. i have the button being shown because of the scriptlet, but i dont think i can make another scriptlet from the onclick function that then displays the getArtistName() function.

Comment: I think it's nice to separate the functions based on what they're doing. For your other question, I believe Sandy Good's comment has the right answer: Your success handler should just look like this: `withSuccessHandler(writeSuccess)` and the script you're calling should return the first parameter of your success handler.

Comment: i changed the `withSuccessHandler` and it returns the artistName, but i need to append it to the unordered list as a list item. im trying to figure out how to get it to display from the server i guess as templated html. like the `<?!= createArtistList ?>`, i need it to stay on the web app and be accessible to anyone from anywhere, not as local storage.

Comment: It'd probably be easiest to just return it as a string and concatenate your server variables into it, so that you return something like `"<li>" + text + "</li>"`. If you want to return a whole template from a file, you could do something like `template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('yourFile');` then return `template.evaluate()`. Then in your client you can append it to the end of the list with something like `$('#yourList').append(serverLi);`.

Comment: What are you seeing? Any error messages on the console? Is the response from the server available to your client code?

Comment: im getting the write failure when trying to return artistName + `'<li>' + text + '</li>'`. also cant call document.getElementById in code.gs file, its a reference error, document is not defined. not sure this is the way to get it to display as templated html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117041/discussion-between-mmaluff-and-user4411473).